# Selecting rows from an HDFStore given list of indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set that does not fit in memory. I'm currently storing this in an HDFStore with 2 tables: `df_hist` is a collection of histograms indexed by a `MultiIndex` where the first level labels the histogram and the second level labels the histogram bin. `df_params` contains simulation parameters used to generate each histogram and is indexed by the histogram labels (i.e. the first level of the `df_hist` index).

```
In [1]: store = pandas.HDFStore('test.h5')

In [2]: store['df_params'].head()
Out[2]: 
    N  z  sample  sigma  oct       T
0  64  6    6235    0.6   22  0.8200
1  64  6    6235    0.6   22  0.8476
2  64  6    6235    0.6   22  0.8757
3  64  6    6235    0.6   22  0.9043
4  64  6    6235    0.6   22  0.9336

In [3]: store['df_hist'].head()
Out[3]: 
               p     p_err
id bin                    
0  0    0.000382  0.000008
   1    0.002010  0.000025
   2    0.005244  0.000038
   3    0.009347  0.000052
   4    0.012662  0.000058
```

What I would like to do is select a subset of the histograms to load using some query on the `df_params` table and then load only the relevant rows from `df_hist`. If the data were able to fit in memory I would do something like:

```
df_params = store['df_params']
df_hist = store['df_hist']
selection = df_params.index[df_params['N']==64]
df = df_hist[df_hist.index.get_level_values('id').isin(selection)]
```

What is the best approach to achieving this when `df_hist` is too large to fit in memory?  Ideally it would be possible to do something like

```
store.select('df_hist', where='id isin selection')
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [HDF5 docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#querying-a-table)? From the example there: `store.select('dfq',"index>Timestamp('20130104') & columns=['A', 'B']")` sounds a lot like what you want. You may have to write a wrapper to do the selection because I'm not sure `isin` is supported.  Also it would need to be in `table` format and not `fixed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [5]: parms = DataFrame({ 'A' : [1,1,2,2,3] })

In [6]: parms
Out[6]: 
   A
0  1
1  1
2  2
3  2
4  3

In [7]: parms.to_hdf('parms.hdf','df',mode='w',format='table',data_columns=['A'])

In [8]: selection = pd.read_hdf('parms.hdf','df',where='A=[2,3]')

In [9]: selection
Out[9]: 
   A
2  2
3  2
4  3

In [10]: hist = DataFrame(np.random.randn(25,1),columns=['data'],
   ....: index=MultiIndex.from_tuples([ (i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5) ],
   ....: names=['l1','l2']))

In [11]: hist
Out[11]: 
           data
l1 l2          
0  0   1.232358
   1  -2.677047
   2  -0.168854
   3   0.538848
   4  -0.678224
1  0   0.092575
   1   1.297578
   2  -1.489906
   3  -1.380054
   4   0.701762
2  0   1.397368
   1   0.198522
   2   1.034036
   3   0.650406
   4   1.823683
3  0   0.045635
   1  -0.213975
   2  -1.221950
   3  -0.145615
   4  -1.187883
4  0  -0.782221
   1  -0.626280
   2  -0.331885
   3  -0.975978
   4   2.006322
```

this works in 0.12

```
In [15]: pd.read_hdf('hist.hdf','df',where=pd.Term('l1','=',selection.index.tolist()))
Out[15]: 
           data
l1 l2          
2  0   1.397368
   1   0.198522
   2   1.034036
   3   0.650406
   4   1.823683
3  0   0.045635
   1  -0.213975
   2  -1.221950
   3  -0.145615
   4  -1.187883
4  0  -0.782221
   1  -0.626280
   2  -0.331885
   3  -0.975978
   4   2.006322
```

This works in master/0.13 as well

```
In [16]: pd.read_hdf('hist.hdf','df',where='l1=selection.index')
Out[16]: 
           data
l1 l2          
2  0   1.397368
   1   0.198522
   2   1.034036
   3   0.650406
   4   1.823683
3  0   0.045635
   1  -0.213975
   2  -1.221950
   3  -0.145615
   4  -1.187883
4  0  -0.782221
   1  -0.626280
   2  -0.331885
   3  -0.975978
   4   2.006322
```

Comment: passing a query of ``lhs=list_of_values`` is equivalent to ``isin``

Answer (score 2):

On 0.19 I am able to use the technique the OP desired:

```
indices = [3,5]
for df in store.select('df', where="index in indices", chunksize=100000):
    print df # prints rows with index 3 or 5.
```

Would have posted as a comment, but unable due to rep.